# Folder open with [application name]

Tags: filesystem, 16.10

On windows I can right click a folder and have "open git bash here" , "open with visual studio"  in the context menu. I'm wondering if I can have the same in ubuntu. If so how?

Answer (score 0):

you can still right click to with a different application. If you want to open something with visual studio, you would first have to install visual studio by using wine. If right clicking is now working at all check you setting under ->system settings ->mouse and touchpad

Comment: Visual studio is available on ubuntu I'm using it and right click is working, you missed the question